# ¿Cómo contar valores de una columna en función de los datos de otra columna en un data frame?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
lirios <- iris[c(1:5, 51:55, 101:105), ]
head(lirios)
```

Me gustaría contar cuántos datos tiene la variable *sepal.length* en función de la especie y crear 3 variables nuevas que resuman el número de datos de *sepal.lenght* para cada especie.

He intentado usar `count()`

Answer (score 0):

Si te entendí bien sería lo siguiente:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% count(Sepal.Length) %>% mutate(sum(n))

# A tibble: 57 x 4
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species Sepal.Length     n `sum(n)`
   <fct>          <dbl> <int>    <int>
 1 setosa           4.3     1       50
 2 setosa           4.4     3       50
 3 setosa           4.5     1       50
 4 setosa           4.6     4       50
 5 setosa           4.7     2       50
 6 setosa           4.8     5       50
 7 setosa           4.9     4       50
 8 setosa           5       8       50
 9 setosa           5.1     8       50
10 setosa           5.2     3       50
# ... with 47 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bien sencilla es creando una tabla de frecuencias mediante `table()` el tema es que además quisieras cada valor en una nueva variable. pero esto último no te lo recomiendo, ya que es más cómodo trabajar con una lista:

```
cantidades <- as.list(table(iris$Species))
cantidades$setosa
[1] 50
```

Si estás usando `count()` seguramente el resultado es un `tibble` por lo que restaría convertirlo en una lista con nombres:

```
iris %>% 
  count(Species) %>% 
  as.list() -> lista


cantidades <- as.list(lista$n)
cantidades <- setNames(cantidades, lista$Species)
```